# How to declare a function that will accept a function with parameters and without parameters in its parameters?

Tags: javascript

how can i execute 2 different functions passed as a parameter to another function , different means function A have no parameters but function B have one parameter , so how i must to declare function C that will accept function A and B in its parameter ?

function A:

```
functionA(){
//func A will call itself after some code in function C
this.functionC(this.functionA);}
```

function B:

```
functionB(e){
//func B will call itself after some code in function C
this.functionC(()=>this.functionB(e));
}
```

function C:

```
functionC(func){
//some code
func;
}
```

With this declarations functionA() is the only one worked , for functionB()it doesnt work maybe the func parameter in functionC(func) must have a parameter too or the call of func inside this functionC must be with a parameter , what do you think to make both A and B functions execute correctly when called by C ?

Comment: Sorry, these codes don't make any sense. What is your actual problem? How does your real code look?

Comment: In the primary function, just test for the existence of your argument(s) and then call the appropriate function based on whether the argument(s) were passed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus so the parameter declaration in C is right ? if yes so the problem is in this line func; ?

Comment: It's really unclear from the code you posted which function does what so I can't really say. Your use of `this.functionC(() => this.function.B(e))` and the other code like it is not clear and probably not what you should be doing in the first place.

Comment: @Bergi my problem is does this 3 functions are right writed ? (when i test B isnt working)

Comment: @ScottMarcus in function B i have an event parameter when i called C function inside it i need to pass that event and from what i found i need arrow function for that , but its seems that functionC isnt ready to accept a function with parameter thats why A works but B doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example shows how to **pass `funcB` and its argument into `funcC` separately** and use them inside of `funcC`.

**In your particular situation** -- where funcB is not expected to receive more than one argument -- **the code would work even if you removed both of the `...`s**. But as long as you're learning how to  use higher-order functions, you might as well learn a more robust way.

The `...` in the definition of `funcC` is called **the `rest` syntax** because it gathers up the "rest" of the arguments into an array (named `args` in this case), which `funcC` can use.

The `...` in the invocation of `someFunc` (inside `funcC`) looks the same, but it has the opposite effect. It's called **the `spread` syntax** because it spreads the array into a number of separate values. (You can see that this is a good thing in the example because `funcB` is expecting a number, not an array of numbers.)

The benefit is that **we can pass `funcC` ANY number of arguments -- as long as the first argument is a function** -- and `funcC` will automagically receive an array including any/all arguments that follow. `funcC` will eventually call `someFunc`, and when it does, it will spread the array out and pass every single argument along as arguments to `someFunc`.

(It's up to us to supply the correct number of "additional" arguments for whatever function we pass as the first argument. For funcA, pass no additional arguments. For funcB, pass 1 additional argument, etc.)

```js
function funcA(){
  output += "\nfuncA";
}

function funcB(num){
  output += "\nfuncB with: " + num;
}

function funcC(someFunc, ...args){
  output += "\nfuncC";
  someFunc(...args);
  console.log(output);
}

function funkY(num, str){
  output += "\nfunkY with: " + num + " and " + str;
}

let output = "";
funcC(funcA);

output = "";
funcC(funcB, 42);

output = "";
funcC(funkY, 42, "woo!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass both A and B functions as callbacks to C like so...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>

        let functionC = function ( callbackA, callbackB ) { 

            // Do some work...

            // If callbackA is a function, call it.
            if ( typeof callbackA === 'function' )
                callbackA();

            // Do some work to get a value to pass to callbackB.
            let value = 'SomeValue';

            // If callbackB is a function, call it.
            if ( typeof callbackB === 'function' )
                callbackB( value );

        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        // Call functionC with callbacks A and B as parameters.
        functionC( 
            function () { console.log('callbackA called!'); },
            function ( param ) { console.log( `callbackB called with param value: ${param}.`) }
        );
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```